# How do I automate the code to run for each row entry in the dataset in R?

Tags: r, string, match

Let's say I have this data frame of several random sentences

```
Sentences<-c("John is playing a video game at the moment","Tom will cook a delicious meal later",
     "Kyle is with his friends watching the game",
     "Diana is hosting her birthday party tomorrow night"
     )
df<-data.frame(a)

keywords<-c("game","is","will","meal","birthday","party")
```

And I have a vector of key words. I need to create a new column in the data frame with only keywords mentioned in the sentence appearing.

```
na.omit(str_match(df[n,],keywords))
```

I have constructed this line of code which returns keywords that were used in those sentences (n stands for row number). How do I automate this code to be applied for each row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `str_extract_all` from `stringr` package for this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
  mutate(new_col = str_extract_all(Sentences, paste(keywords, collapse = "|")))
```

```
                                           Sentences             new_col
1         John is playing a video game at the moment            is, game
2               Tom will cook a delicious meal later          will, meal
3         Kyle is with his friends watching the game        is, is, game
4 Diana is hosting her birthday party tomorrow night is, birthday, party
```

Comment: Oh that works, thank you so much!! I spent way too much time today trying to solve this issue